# How to use Java streams and reduce() to get the sum of calculations with the key and value of the Map?

Tags: java, dictionary, stream, sum, reduce

I'll try to keep it as brief as possible.

I hava this map: Map<Neuron,Float> connections. It contains a Neuron-Objekt as Key and the weight of the connection as value.

The Neuron class has a method "getOutput" to get the output-Value of the neuron.

What I want to do is to go over every neuron in the map, calculate neuron.getOutput * connections.get(neuron) and sum all of that into one variable together.

Is there an elegant way to do this with Java-Streams? Maybe with reduce? I tried it but couldn't get it to work properly.

```
inputConnections.keySet().stream().reduce(
            0f,
            (accumulatedFloat, inputNeuron) -> accumulatedFloat + inputConnections.get(inputNeuron),
            Float::sum);
```

I guess the 0f results in everything getting multiplied with 0.

This code seems to work, but I'd like a more elegant solution.

```
AtomicReference<Float> tmp = new AtomicReference<>(0f);
    inputConnections.keySet().forEach(inputNeuron -> {
        tmp.updateAndGet(v -> new Float((float) (v + inputNeuron.getOutput() * inputConnections.get(inputNeuron))));
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

you can also achieve the same with map and sum

```java
inputConnections.entrySet().stream().mapToDouble(entry -> entry.getKey().getOutput() * entry.getValue()).sum()
```

Answer (score 3):

Your approach using *reduce* is (almost) correct. It should look like the second code snippet where you multiply the neuron's `output` with the value from the map (`inputConnections.get(..)`)

```
inputConnections.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .reduce(0f,
                (result, entry) -> result + entry.getKey().getOutput() * entry.getValue(),
                Float::sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [parallel streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html#executing_streams_in_parallel) (be careful: only makes sense with huge datasets). In case you need some statistics additional to the `sum`, the collector `summarizingDouble` is helpful:

```
DoubleSummaryStatistics sumStat = connections.entrySet().parallelStream()
                .map(entry -> Double.valueOf(entry.getKey().getOutput() * entry.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.summarizingDouble(Double::doubleValue));
System.out.println(sumStat);
```

Example output:
DoubleSummaryStatistics{count=3, sum=18.000000, min=4.000000, average=6.000000, max=8.000000}

Here is a shorter version (thank you [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1180351/rob-spoor) for your comment):

```
sumStat = connections.entrySet().parallelStream()
        .mapToDouble(entry -> entry.getKey().getOutput() * entry.getValue())
        .summaryStatistics();
```

Comment: If you `mapToDouble`, you can replace the `collect` step with `summaryStatistics()`.

Comment: This looks interesting. I'm not quite sure if I could use this in my application though. My neural networks will be very small. But I'll have a lot of individual small networks that are going to be processed.